# Pointer to pointer in C than local function parameter

Tags: c

This question is formulated in the style that I will introduce the reader to the issue at the beginning and in the end I will introduce my problem to him in order to best understand my situation.

In this protocol: [enter link description here](https://github.com/assaabloy-ppi/salt-channel-c)
the salt_channel_t structure is created, which definitely contains the necessary cryptographic variables, which I use in the program to perform cryptographic operations such as data encryption, data decryption, user authentication and the like.

```
typedef struct salt_channel_s {
    
    /* Encryption and signature stuff */
    uint8_t     ek_common[api_crypto_box_BEFORENMBYTES];    /**< Symmetric session encryption key. */
    uint8_t     peer_sk_pub[api_crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];/**< Peer public signature key. */
    uint8_t     my_sk_sec[api_crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];  /**< My secret signature key. */
    uint8_t     *my_sk_pub;                             /**< My public signature key, points to &my_sk_sec[32]. */
    uint8_t     write_nonce[api_crypto_box_NONCEBYTES];     /**< Write nonce. */
    uint8_t     read_nonce[api_crypto_box_NONCEBYTES];      /**< Read nonce. */


    salt_io_channel_t   write_channel;                  /**< Write channel structure. */
    salt_io_impl        write_impl;                     /**< Function pointer to write implementation. */
    salt_io_channel_t   read_channel;                   /**< Read channel structure. */
    salt_io_impl        read_impl;                      /**< Function pointer to read implementation. */

     
    uint8_t     *hdshk_buffer;                          /**< Handshake buffer, used only during handshake. */
    uint32_t    hdshk_buffer_size;                      /**< Handshake buffer size >= SALT_HNDSHK_BUFFER_SIZE. */
} salt_channel_t;
```

I am attaching a part of the structure, it is not complete, I just wanted to zoom in on it.

I gradually fill this structure with functions such as salt_create (), salt_init_session () and the like. I created a variable of type salt_channel_t called client_channel or server_channel (depending on whether it is a client or server),

```
salt_channel_t client_channel;
salt_channel_t server_channel;
```

which, however, is an ordinary variable of the pointer type. Since the functions of the salt protocol have formal parameters, mostly of the pointer type, I access them classically via the & operator. eg:

```
salt_create(&client_channel, SALT_CLIENT, (salt_io_impl) &dummy, (salt_io_impl) &dummy, NULL);
salt_init_session(&client_channel, client_buffer, sizeof(client_buffer));
```

However, the following function:

```
salt_ret_t salti_wrap(salt_channel_t *p_channel,
                      uint8_t *p_data,
                      uint32_t size,
                      uint8_t header,
                      uint8_t **wrapped,
                      uint32_t *wrapped_length,
                      bool last_msg);
```

should perform data encryption.
I.e., the usage will be:
param p_channel         Pointer to salt channel structure.
param p_data            Pointer to clear text message.
param size              Size of clear text message.
param type              Type of message.
param wrapped           Return pointer to where the raw message to send begins.
param wrapped_length    Return length of raw wrapped message.

And the encrypted block that I want to send over the network channel using TCP, for example, should be stored in param wrapped and the length of this block in param wrapped_length. Using the function:

```
salti_io_write(client_channel, client_channel.write_channel.p_data, client_channel.write_channel.size);
```

this encrypted block of a certain size is then sent via a channel to the other party.
This is a whole body function:

```
salt_ret_t salti_wrap(salt_channel_t *p_channel,
                      uint8_t *p_data,
                      uint32_t size,
                      uint8_t header,
                      uint8_t **wrapped,
                      uint32_t *wrapped_length,
                      bool last_msg)
{

    int ret;
    memset(p_data, 0x00, api_crypto_box_ZEROBYTES);

    p_data[32] = header;
    p_data[33] = 0x00;

    //crypto function
    ret = api_crypto_box_afternm(p_data,
                                 p_data,
                                 size + SALT_WRAP_OVERHEAD_SIZE,
                                 p_channel->write_nonce,
                                 p_channel->ek_common);


    p_data[14] = SALT_ENCRYPTED_MSG_HEADER_VALUE;
    p_data[15] = (last_msg) ? SALT_LAST_FLAG : 0x00U;

    /*
     * size is of cleartext message, with time[4], header[2], MAC[16] and header[2] the size if 24 bytes larger.
     */
    salti_u32_to_bytes(&p_data[10], size + SALT_WRAP_OVERHEAD_IO_SIZE);

    /*
     * The 4 size bytes are serialized. The size to send is 4 bytes more.
     */
    *wrapped = &p_data[10];
    *wrapped_length = size + SALT_WRAP_OVERHEAD_IO_SIZE + SALT_LENGTH_SIZE;

    return SALT_SUCCESS;

}
```

And I call this function these rules:

```
salti_wrapped(&client_channel,&client_channel.hdshk_buffer[SALT_M3_HOST_WRAPPED_OFFSET], size, SALT_M3_HEADER_VALUE, &client_channel.write_channel.p_data, &client_channel.write_channel.size, false);
```

I know this is bullshit and I will never get to encrypted data that way. I can't advise myself on how to fix it skillfully in office so that it does its job properly. Does anyone have any clever idea how to solve this problem?

I expect the output to be encrypted and stored in a wrapped variable of wrapped_length. However, in the wrapped variable, they don't mean the same thing, and wrapped _length comes out to me around 4237841, which is also a total delusion.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It reads like you're not getting the expected output. You should describe what you are expecting for a given input and what you are getting instead.

Comment: This is the time to learn how to use a debugger. Step through your code and watch it and the variables.